# Google closure compiler method converted to global function

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I have this simple code: 
( I removed some code to keep it simple... )

```
if(!window['PSI']) window['PSI'] = {};
/**@constructor*/
window['PSI']['Select'] = function(pattern) {
 this.highlight(pattern);
}
window['PSI']['Select'].prototype = {
highlight: function( pattern) {
    var regex = (typeof pattern === 'string') ? new RegExp(pattern, 'i') : pattern;
    var highlight = function(node) {
        if (node.nodeType === 3) {
            var pos = node.data.search(a);

        } else if (node.nodeType === 1 ) {
            for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i) {
                i += highlight(node.childNodes[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    var items = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
        highlight(items[i]);
    }
}
```

}

and after i run 
`java -jar closure-compiler-v20160713.jar --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS --js source.js --js_output_file source.min.js`

here is the output:

```
window.PSI || (window.PSI = {});
window.PSI.Select = function() { g() };
window.PSI.Select.prototype = {};
function g() {
function e(b) {
  if(3 === b.nodeType) b.data.search(a);
  else if(1 === b.nodeType) for (var c = 0; c < b.childNodes.length; ++c)c += e(b.childNodes[c])
  }
  for (var f = document.getElementsByTagName("li"), d = 0; d < f.length; ++d)e(f[d])
 };
```

my highlight method becomes a global function, is there any way to keep my method as a prototype of PSI.Select object?
It's strange that not all my methods are acting like this, only 2 ... this is one of them

Answer (score 0):

i had to add --generate_exports and --export_local_property_definitions flags and /** @export */ before my method, it seems that the compiler noticed that my method never referenced 'this' and it decided that removing it from the prototype was safe, but i didn't want that. If anyone has a better suggestion please do.

Comment: It has nothing to do with "this". It just decided it could devitualized it.  Exporting your interface is the right thing to do.  You need to clearly separate your external interface otherwise you are relying on the compiler implementation details and the shape and usage of the methods in the code.